# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter' in databricks

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to save the content of pandas dataframe to excel file in windows/azure databricks.
import pandas as pd

## Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

## Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

## Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

## Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.

writer.save()

Error >>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

at line #2 pd.ExcelWriter()

databricks cluster is running on spark 2.4.4
Any suggestion on how to fix this ?

Comment: Looks like its not installed? Did you install XlsxWriter using  `pip install XlsxWriter`

Comment: and also remember to import xlsxwriter by adding `import xlsxwriter`

Comment: I get "Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter ..." when I try pip install xlsxwriter.

Comment: I changed the engine from "xlsxwtier" to "openpyxl" the error is gone.  But gives me "
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pandas_simple.xlsx'" on the save()

Comment: add the import under your pandas import `import xlsxwriter`

Comment: @JohnT import doesn't work. gives me same error "No module named 'xlsxwriter' "

Comment: I recreated the error sometimes you need to restart the kernel

Comment: Oh its probably the databrick saving then this should help for that https://towardsdatascience.com/databricks-how-to-save-files-in-csv-on-your-local-computer-3d0c70e6a9ab

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have XlsxWriter installed

```
 pip install XlsxWriter
```

you might need to restart the kernel[image]

also, remember to import

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not see kernal options. I would check with admins. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107489/databricks-writing-spark-dataframe-directly-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

you can check the documentation.

```
enginestr (optional)
```

Engine to use for writing. If None, defaults to io.excel..writer. NOTE: can only be passed as a keyword argument.

Deprecated since version 1.2.0: As the xlwt package is no longer maintained, the xlwt engine will be removed in a future version of pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html